# Generate hierarchical data using python

Tags: python, data-structures, networkx

I need to create Directory and sub-directory structure for a MxN size ( M levels , N sub-levels). Is there any Tree data structure in Python that could help me do it?

Example:

**Input:**

3 x 2 ( 3 Levels and 2 sub-levels for each of 3 levels)

**Output:**

```
1

 11
  111
  112
 12
  121
  122

------
2

 21
  211
  212
 22
  221
  222
----
3
 31
  311
  312
 32
  321
  322
```

Comment: I have updated my question - 3 is height ; 2 is depth for each level

Comment: Sorry - i didn't mean it as a matrix input - wrong usage of words. I was mentioning that to say i need to create "3 Levels" and ever level should have depth of 2.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple different data structures that would work for an application like this.

My *first* intuition is to use nested dictionaries of matrices, as this would give you the multi-level indexing behavior that you're looking for and can be implemented in pure Python. Since your proposed data tree is of size *MxN* (and is thus rectangular), you could also use a `pandas.DataFrame`, which supports row/column indexing similar to a nested dictionary. But ultimately, I think a `numpy.ndarray` is a [*much* better fit in terms of scalability](https://realpython.com/numpy-tensorflow-performance/).

Nevertheless, I'll provide an example of each.

### Using Pure Python

In pure Python, a *MxN* matrix of integers is typically represented by a list of lists of integers, the [type hint](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) for which would be `list[list[int]]`.

A data structured like `level/sublevel/matrix` with `level/sublevel` pairs like `2/21` could be represented by a structure like `dict[dict[Matrix]]`, which would make type hint for the complete data structure something like `dict[dict[list[list[int]]]]`.

The following nested dictionary comprehension will generate the proposed structure and contains the exact same data as is provided in your example case:

```
M = 3
N = 2

data = {
    i : {
        10 * i + j : [
            [i, j, k] for k in range(1, N + 1)
        ] for j in range(1, N + 1)
    } for i in range(1, M + 1)
}
```

The result of which can be seen using `pprint.pprint`:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(data)
{1: {11: [[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 2]], 12: [[1, 2, 1], [1, 2, 2]]},
 2: {21: [[2, 1, 1], [2, 1, 2]], 22: [[2, 2, 1], [2, 2, 2]]},
 3: {31: [[3, 1, 1], [3, 1, 2]], 32: [[3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 2]]}}
```

Any particular matrix can then be retrieved by its level and sublevel indices:

```
>>> data[2][21]
[[2, 1, 1], [2, 1, 2]]
```

### Using a `pandas.DataFrame`

If you don't mind invoking third-party libraries, you could take this a step further converting it into a `pandas.DataFrame` and simplifying the sublevel index:

```
import pandas as pd

M = 3
N = 2

data = {
    i : {
        j : [
            [i, j, k] for k in range(1, N + 1)
        ] for j in range(1, N + 1)
    } for i in range(1, M + 1)
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

The result of which is the following:

```
>>> df
                        1                       2                       3
1  [[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 2]]  [[2, 1, 1], [2, 1, 2]]  [[3, 1, 1], [3, 1, 2]]
2  [[1, 2, 1], [1, 2, 2]]  [[2, 2, 1], [2, 2, 2]]  [[3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 2]]
```

Which, with the simplified sublevel index, gives its element matrices like so:

```
>>> df[2][1]  # Equivalent to data[2][21] in the pure Python example.
[[2, 1, 1], [2, 1, 2]]
```

### Using a `numpy.ndarray`

At this point, you might note that the data structure in question is in fact just an *MxN* matrix of *MxN* matrices. So if you wanted to, you could reduce this into an *MxNxMxN* 4D array by switching from dictionary comprehensions to list comprehensions and invoking `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np

M = 3
N = 2

data = [
    [
        [
            [i, j, k] for k in range(1, N + 1)
        ] for j in range(1, N + 1)
    ] for i in range(1, M + 1)
]

data = np.array(data)
```

Which, in this example, results in the following array of shape `(3, 2, 3, 2)`:

```
>>> data
array([[[[1, 1, 1],
         [1, 1, 2]],

        [[1, 2, 1],
         [1, 2, 2]]],


       [[[2, 1, 1],
         [2, 1, 2]],

        [[2, 2, 1],
         [2, 2, 2]]],


       [[[3, 1, 1],
         [3, 1, 2]],

        [[3, 2, 1],
         [3, 2, 2]]]])
```

For which indexing is off-by-one relative to the `pandas.DataFrame` case, as array indices start from zero:

```
>>> data[1][0]  # Equivalent to df[2][1] in the pandas example.
array([[2, 1, 1],
       [2, 1, 2]])
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response. Would same code work for 5x5 ?

Comment: @kn9 If you mean the data structure, then yes, it should work for any MxN matrix. If you mean generating the particular pattern of the sample output you provided, then also yes, the nested dictionary comprehension should take care of that.

Comment: Ok, Thank you. I only see array max length 3. I will play around variables /code to make it more dynamic. Thanks again.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean! That can be fixed by replacing the `k` in `[i, j, k]` with an unpacked iterable like `*range(...)`, but to get more specific, I'd need to know what rule is being used to generate the digits beyond the first two columns, which seem to just be the `[i, j]` indices of the matrix within the MxN data structure. For the 3x2 matrix, the `k` column just seems to trivially increment with the row number, but the pattern becomes less clear with more columns.

Comment: Let me try to make it visual descritpion. For naming i am trying to name which signifies Parent-> Parent(of)child --> Parent(Parent(of)child) of child

https://pastebin.com/8izyDNZv

Comment: Okay, I think I understand a little better, but I still have a few unresolved ambiguities. Could you demonstrate what you're imagining it would look like for a 3x3? i.e., with N=3, would there be three subdirectories per level for three levels below the root?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245307/discussion-between-kn9-and-erick-shepherd).

Comment: Hope i didn't make too many mistakes for 3x3-- https://pastebin.com/iP0bqXXT

Comment: I hope this graph may help better : https://imgur.com/anLPD4L